# Spring boot validation - two arrays with the same length

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, validation

I receive in JSON two arrays. The length of arrays have to be equal. Is it possible to check it using Spring Validation?

```
"Fields": {
        "Type": [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2],
        "Value": [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 5]
    }
```

Comment: Could you please provide the code for your DTO object and controller? From your question it's not clear whether you're gonna to implement JSR303 validation using @Valid annotation or using spring Validator.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this by creating a bean, which implements the Validator interface. Inside this bean, validate length of the arrays you want and in the controller, annotate the parameter you want to accept, for which you created validation in the above bean, as @Valid.